# How to add multiple stop points for routing using ArcGis in Android

Tags: java, android, routes, maps, arcgis

I have a project where in I have a source and a destination, but in between there can be any number of stop points. I need to display a route from source to destination covering all the stop points.

I started finding route between two points and is working fine. But the moment I add a extra point in between it gives a error saying

> Location "Location 3" in "Stops" is unlocated.  Location "Location 2" in "Stops" is on a soft-restricted network element.  Cannot preserve last location "Location 3" in "Stops" because it is invalid.  "Stops" does not contain valid input for any route.

I tried googling for this error but couldn't find any results.

I thought location 3 is not a valid location but when I try to find a route between source and location 3 it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below I have attached function which gives route result.

```
private void QueryDirections(final ArrayList<Point> stopPoints) {

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RoutingSample.this, "Routing Sample",
            "Calculating route...", true);
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Start building up routing parameters
                NAFeaturesAsFeature stops = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
                ArrayList<StopGraphic> stopGraphics = new ArrayList<StopGraphic>();
                for(Point pt : stopPoints){
                    stopGraphics.add(new StopGraphic(pt));
                }
                Graphic[] stopGraphicsPrim = new Graphic[stopGraphics.size()];
                stopGraphicsPrim = stopGraphics.toArray(stopGraphicsPrim);
                stops.setSpatialReference(wm);
                stops.setFeatures(stopGraphicsPrim);
                stops.setCompressedRequest(true);
                RouteParameters rp = mRouteTask
                        .retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
                rp.setStops(stops);
                rp.setReturnDirections(true);
                rp.setFindBestSequence(true);
                rp.setPreserveFirstStop(true);
                rp.setOutSpatialReference(wm);

                // I get error here. When routeTast.solve is called. Please help

                mResults = mRouteTask.solve(rp);
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mException = e;
                e.printStackTrace();
                dialog.dismiss();
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"directions cannot be found ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    // Start the operation
    t.start();

}
```

I was referring to a similar post [Multiple Routing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141556/arcgis-android-finding-the-shortest-route-between-multiple-stops?rq=1) 
But I wasn't able to get any solution from this. Please help. Thank You in advance.